# Has anybody ever heard of "deadlinkchecker" crashing httpd?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

Earlier today, we had a strange occurrence: it seems that an employee used something called "deadlinkchecker.com" on our web site (running Apache httpd on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance), and the whole instance crashed. When I then waded through the httpd log, I found nearly 800 requests from this "deadlinkchecker.com" within about a 20-minute period (during which there were very few requests from elsewhere), some of which required several minutes to satisfy. In effect, we appear to have accidentally initiated a DoS attack on ourselves.

Has anybody here ever heard of such a thing? Does anybody here know anything about this "deadlinkchecker.com"?

**Update**

I hadn't checked the error log initially. I found several hundred error log entries in the same timeframe as the problem, of the form,

```
[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid nnnn] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 74.208.42.172:ppppp] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

with a variety of different port numbers (and the IP address is that of deadlinkchecker.com). This was then followed (after an entry indicating a shutdown) by a few hundred entries indicating a refused connection.

**Update**
Looking at the AWS monitoring, we had a minor CPU spike and a large network-out spike (but I see nothing suspicious in the httpd logs) beginning about a minute before the massive burst of traffic from deadlinkchecker.com began, immediately followed by a steady build in CPU usage as the crisis developed, and a network-in spike that began right as the CPU usage was peaking.

Comment: That’s only 1.5 attempts per second over a 1.2K second window (20 minutes). You have not given us enough to diagnose your issue. Have you heard of a website isn't really something within our scope here at Super User since we are not a discussion forum

Comment: That's still more traffic in 20 minutes than the site normally gets in four hours. And I'm grasping at straws for any indication of what happened.

Comment: How about the logs outward-facing within your AWS account? Like CPU/Memory/I/O usage on the instance itself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.